# If $\exists n \in \mathbb{Z+}$,s.t. $2^n + 1$ is a prime, prove $\exists k \in \mathbb{Z+}, n = 2^k$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

The actual description of the question is: 
Suppose that $2^n + 1$ is a prime where $n$ is a positive integer. Prove that
$n = 2^k$ for some positive integer $k$.

There is only one approach that know of: 
 To show that there is factorization in which at least one factor $(x-a)=1$, and the others are prime. A nice simplification would be to show that all except one root is having value such that the factor has value = $1$.  
 For example, if given quadratic: $x^2 + 2x - 3 = (x+3)(x-1)$. As have two factors, so one of these factors to be $1$, and the other prime. 
This leads to:
 $$x-1=1 \implies x=2 \implies (x+3)(x-1) = 5$$
else, $$x+3=1 \implies x = -2 \implies (x-1)(x+3) => -3$$

But, if consider positive integers then $x=2$ is the value.

if given quadratic: $x^2 - 5x +6 = (x-3)(x-2)$. As have two factors, so one of these factors to be $1$, and the other prime. 
This leads to:
 $$x-3=1 \implies x=4 \implies (x-3)(x-2) = 2$$
else, $$x-2=1 \implies x = 3 \implies (x-3)(x-2) => 0$$

But, if consider that $0$ is not a prime, then $x=4$ is the value.

So, let us try to work out cases with value of $k$ starting form $0$.
$k=0, 2^0=1, 2^1+1 =3$
$k=1, 2^1=2, 2^2 +1=5$

So, weak induction will suffice here, as strong induction is not needed as no need for previous values to prove new case.

So, let the assumption be that it holds for $k=l$, need prove for $k=l+1$, 
 but, $2^{2^{l+1}} = 2^{{2^l}^2} = (2^{2^l})^2$
So, if $2^{2^l} + 1$ is a prime, let p; then need prove $(p-1)^2+1$ is also.

i.e., need prove $p^2-2p+2$ is a prime, given $p$ is.

Comment: For example $7^2 - 7\cdot 5 +2=16$

Comment: @rtybase So, it is a failure.

Comment: Let's put it in a positive light, you just need another approach :)

Comment: @rtybase Can the reason can be given algebraically without any value of $p$, as there is negative discriminant of $p^2 -2p+2 $. so, no real root is possible. Any other approach is not coming to me, can you please suggest.

Comment: Maybe ... but if you try to prove a statement which has counterexamples, you don't really have to look for an algebraic reason for that (unless you insist of course), the statement is wrong. I meant, you need a different strategy to prove that **if $2^n+1$ is prime, then $n=2^k$ for some $k$**. I find it easy to use modular arithmetics, plus learning modular arithmetics is not so difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also from $2 \equiv -1 \pmod{3} \Rightarrow 2^{2k+1} \equiv (-1)^{2k+1} \equiv -1 \pmod{3}$. Since we ask for $2^n+1$ to be prime (thus it can't be divisible by 3, unless $n=1=2^0$), $n$ must be even or $n=2k_0$, then it becomes $4^{k_0}+1$ which is $4^{k_0} \equiv -1 \pmod{5}$ for odd $k_0$ so (unless $n=2^1$) it must be even $k_0=2k_1$ and $n=2^2k_1$ and so on by induction. This process stops for some $k_t$ s.t. $\frac{n}{2^{k_t}}\leq 1$.

Answer (score 2):

We have:

$$2^{ab} + 1 = (2^{a} + 1)(2^{a(b-1)} - 2^{a(b-2)} + \cdots + 1)$$

where $b$ is an odd integer. It's obvious that both of the factors are bigger than 1 and so if $n$ has an odd factor we $2^n + 1$ has a nontrivial factor.

If you're more interested in primes of that form, they are called [Fermat's Primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number) and till now only five of them are known.

Comment: in my edited OP, have got $p^2 -2p +2$ to be proved as a prime, if $p$ is. Please link your answer to that, if I am correct.