# How to prove $p=2^{2^s}+1$ for some $s \in \Bbb N$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers

If $p-1$ is a power of $2$ where $p$ is prime how to prove that $p=2^{2^s}+1$ for some $s \in \Bbb N$.

Surely, $p=2^k+1$ then what will we use next?

P.S: I got it finally. We have to use $(a-b)|(a^n -b^n)$ then we have to use that $(2^r+1)|(2^k+1)$ if $k=rs$ with $s$ odd; leading to a contradiction.

So I am using a tag of proof verification.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $\exists n \in \mathbb{Z+}$,s.t. $2^n + 1$ is a prime, prove $\exists k \in \mathbb{Z+}, n = 2^k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2624815/if-exists-n-in-mathbbz-s-t-2n-1-is-a-prime-prove-exists-k-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be more detailed in your argument. Since $p-1=2^k$ we have $p=2^k+1$. Assume now that $k=mn$ and continue like here:

[If $2^n+1$ is prime, why must $n$ be a power of $2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140804/if-2n1-is-prime-why-must-n-be-a-power-of-2)

So $p$ is not prime, if $k$ is not a power of $2$. Hence we have $k=2^s$ and $p=2^{2^s}+1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $k$ contains an odd prime $p$; let $k=pd$ then note that

$(2^{d})^{p}-(-1)^{p}$ = $(2^{d}+1)(\sum_{j=0}^{j=p-1}{2^{dj}(-1)^{j}}$)